# Unable to pass variable data

Tags: php, session

I am trying to use the following code to pass information to another site but it keeps giving me an error:

### Invalid Code:

```
$a = $b->doIt("James",$_SESSION['JNum'],"Frank");
```

### Valid Sample Code:

```
$a = $b->doIt("James","123456","Frank");
```

In the first example, the page returns "number field is required". The second piece of sample code returns valid results. Do to the nature of this project though I need to pass the id number as they are stored in SESSION variables.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you start the session with:

```
session_start();
```

Comment: I am a total idiot - just noticed my mistake right before your post. Thanks Fabian!

Answer (score 1):

you're missing $_SESSION['JNum']

```
var_dump($_SESSION['JNum']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not only see if $_SESSION['JNum'] is set, using var_dump, but also make sure sessions are started at the top of yours script:

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['JNum']);
```